# why box height is greater than line-height

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  line-height: 30px;
}

a {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="">测试</a>
</div>
```

I believe the content height is the same as `line-height` which is `30px`. But actually in Chrome, it's `32px`. Why is that?

Comment: Please choose a correct answer if any of answers helped you to fix that problem so the others doesn't have why to keep trying anymore on this

Answer (score 3):

Because `<a />` has it's own line height, which is above 1.0.

Add this line in CSS:

```
a {
    /* current styles */
    line-height: 1;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrERPP

Comment: It's ok. But I met another problem,it seems the space top the word is bigger than space lower the word? why ?

Comment: It may depend on how font is designed or browser rendering. It make me sick sometimes, too, but not a big deal for me :)

Comment: you can use vertical-align: middle; check in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Because the `line-height` depends in `font-size`
 Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2qd5yvuj/) i just changed the `font-size` and the height is `30px`

also you need `vertical-align: middle;` for the `<a>` so the space from top and bottom to be equal